# Continuous serial number generation (incl. duplicate values)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA macro which assigns a *unique serial number* in column **B** based on a list of values given in column **A**. I have managed to come up with a simple macro, which assigns a *serial number* for each row in my spreadsheet (regardless of the value).

However, my workbook also contains duplicates entries in column **A**, for which I would like the *unique serial* to repeat until the next new string.

```
Sub serialgenerator()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(2, 2).Formula = CLng("1")
Cells(2, 2).Autofill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)), Type:=xlFillSeries
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: start with entering the value `1` in B2, and this function in B3  `=IF(A2=A3,B2,B2+1)`. No you can copy this function down from B3 to the end of the list.

Comment: Is number in  column A order in increase arrangement?

Comment: Hi Ivan, 

Not specifically, but I can definitely set that before running the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
'demo    
Cells.Clear
bigno = 12345
For i = 1 To 20
Cells(i, 1) = bigno
If Rnd > 0.8 Then bigno = bigno + Int(Rnd * 10000) + 10000
Next i
'code
usn = 1
Cells(1, 2) = usn
For i = 2 To 20
If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then usn = usn + 1
Cells(i, 2) = usn
Next i
```

If a cell is different to it's predecessor, then the Unique Serial Number is increased, otherwise it remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Unique (Dictionary, Array)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SerialGenerator()
    
    ' Define Last Row.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Write Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Using the dictionary, get the unique values and at the same time
    ' write them to Data Array overwriting the original values with
    ' the unique values for each row.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Curr As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Curr = Data(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(Curr) Then
            If Not IsEmpty(Curr) Then
                If Not dict.Exists(Curr) Then
                    j = j + 1
                    dict(Curr) = j
                End If
                Data(i, 1) = dict(Curr)
            'Else ' IsEmpty(Curr)
            End If
        'Else ' IsError(Curr)
            'data(i,1) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
    rng.Offset(, 1).Value = Data

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have sorted Column A so they're in numerical order (as in it goes like 10,10,11,12,12,13 not like 10,11,12,10,13,12 etc) then this code is probably as simple as it gets:

```
Dim lastrow As Long, Counter As Long

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Counter = 0

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Range("A" & i) <> Range("A" & i - 1) Then
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Range("B" & i) = Counter
    Else
        Range("B" & i) = Counter
    End If
Next i
```